# Disable mouse 4 and mouse 5 going back and forward on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint

On Linux Mint, mouse 4 and mouse 5 are automatically bound to go back and forward in the file manager, all browsers, settings, and probably elsewhere. I was wondering if it was possible to disable this functionality *without* completely disabling mouse 4 and mouse 5.

The reason for this is I use mouse 4 for push to talk, and having the browser or the file manager go back whenever I want to talk is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You can remap the buttons with xinput

$ `xinput` 
This should list your input devices. Note the id of your mouse.

$ `xinput get-button-map <mouse-id>` (mouse id was 14 in my case)

This will print something like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`

$ `xinput set-button-map <mouse-id> 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

This will disable all except the primary buttons.

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=241162

To persist the remap on reboot, create and save the following file-

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/my-mouse-config.conf

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "<mouse-name>"
    Option  "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

source - https://askubuntu.com/a/407889/75357

Answer (score 0):

The reason mouse buttons 4 and 5 go "back and forward" is that these are the mouse buttons that correspond to scroll wheel move events. So all applications that respond to scroll wheel events will respond to those buttons.

You can use the `ButtonMapping` option in the X `evdev` driver section of your `xorg.conf` file to map your "mouse 4" to another event, e.g. "button 6", and then configure "button 6" for push to talk.

See `man evdev` for details. Look at your `Xorg.log` to figure out if your configuration worked after restarting the X server.